# Cannot view all the messages sent in a thread on careers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

I tried reviewing a reply I sent to someone who contacted me on careers.stackoverflow. Despite being told that the there were two messages in the thread, I was only able to see the first message. I then went to the 'Sent' folder where I saw the start of the message that I had sent. When I clicked it, I was unable to see my message, but only the first message to which I replied. Has anyone else noticed this or am I just a newb?

Comment: Where you see two messages mentioned? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I've had a look at your account and I can't reproduce this. I can see both messages in the thread, and this works from both the Inbox and Sent folders. If you're still seeing a problem, please update your post with a screenshot, or send it to careers@stackoverflow.com if you don't want to post it publicly.